# My question has been put on hold citing a rule that I think I haven't broken. Is there any way to appeal the decision?

Tags: support, on-hold

I have [asked a question](https://superuser.com/q/1456112/337631) on Super User a few days ago. As it is common on the StackExchange family, it's quite an obscure, but very specific scenario, and I think unopinionated, objective answers exist for solving it. I received a few views, even one upvote, but then my question has been put on hold by a moderator, deeming it to be a question "seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations". I very strongly believe it is not.

I made small edits to the parts that I think might have caused confusion for the person marking my question to be put on hold, politely explained my disagreement, and waited patiently hoping that they will reconsider their decision, or at least give me more details on what I did wrong. Obviously, I really would like the "on hold" status to be removed from my question in the hope that someone, somewhere might have an answer to it.

What is the recommended course of action in this scenario?

Comment: From the [On-topic page of super user](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic): *and it is not about …cell phones or smart phones* and that seems to be the core of your question.

Comment: Do note that questions that are edited shortly after being put on hold are placed in a review queue to consider them for potential reopening. In this case, it [was reviewed, but the reviewers decided not to reopen it](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/888969).

Comment: Dániel, can you help us test something?  You weren't aware of the reopen review on your question.  We've created a user script to allow people to see that, but we don't know what minimum privilege level is needed for it to work.  We know that some level is required because it doesn't work if you aren't logged in.  Your rep is still relatively low on SU.  Could you load the script and see if it works for you?  It's described here: [Announcement: New Functionality](https://meta.superuser.com/a/13721/364367).  (cont'd)

Comment: Also, we're not sure what rep is required to view the timeline on a question.  This is a link for yours: https://superuser.com/posts/1456112/timeline.  Are you able to view that?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can view the timeline, yes

Comment: @fixer1234 I have added the userscript you suggested, and it says this: _"A reopen review has been found
Any existing votes will not be reset by future edits.

Status could not be determined because you do not have review privileges."_ The link to the reopen review works, and I am able to view it with my current rep.

Comment: @DánielKis-Nagy, thanks.  This is surprising because the script reads the info from the timeline data.  I would have thought that if you can see the timeline, and see the review results directly, there wouldn't be anything in the script requiring higher permissions.  It looks like for some reason the user needs review privileges for the script to see the review results.  Appreciate your checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is there any way to appeal the decision?**

As gparyani commented, there was already an automatic "appeal".  Your edit bumped the question into a review queue where the community looked at the revised question.  The reviewers assessed that it should not be reopened.  The main other way to ask for a question to be reconsidered is to raise it here in Meta, which this post does.

Note that questions are presented in the reopen review queue only once.  So if you figure out a way to edit the question so that it is computer-centric (see my second point), you would need to post here to make people aware of it.

**Should it be reopened?**

Questions can have more than one closure issue, but only one reason can be selected when voting to close. You fixed the product recommendation aspect, but it still has another issue, which rene commented on.

Phones are off-topic unless the question focuses on a computer (the subject area of the site), and the phone is part of the picture.  As the question is framed, a computer is only tangential. The question centers on actions you can take with the phone to get around the fact that it's broken.

To me, the question isn't about a computer enough to be on-topic here. The kinds of workarounds you're asking about, and what you really want to know, would best be answered on one of our sites that focus on mobile phones.  There are separate sites for the different mobile platforms.  I'm not familiar with what OS that Nokia model uses, so unfortunately, I don't know which site to recommend (perhaps a reader will comment on that).

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that it is "NokiaOS 2.5.1" but that appears to just be a codename. Maybe some flavour of Symbian?

Comment: Thanks! I'm fine with my question not being reopened now that I see that (1) it actually was reconsidered (2) there was a good reason for it to be put on hold. I think the main source of confusion for me was that citing a single rule gave me an impression that that's the only serious issue with my question, but now I understand that that's a limitation of the system.

Comment: @DánielKis-Nagy Worth noting that over on Meta Stack Exchange, we're discussing how to resolve issue 1. Your opinion is appreciated: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323786/how-can-we-communicate-to-users-who-try-and-get-their-question-reopened-that-the

Answer (score 2):

The are ways to appeal such a decision, but the decision isn't incorrect; such an appeal would be unsuccessful. You can check that it is off-topic by [viewing their help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Looking on Android.SE is helpful since searching for "[broken screen files](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=broken%20screen%20files)" there produces **94** results, the method of using software on a PC and a cable to remotely control the phone is similar enough to explain the method.

The "Nokia 2600 Classic" is not an Android phone, and we don't have a site for [NokiaOS 2.5.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_2600_classic#Operating_system), so we don't have somewhere to ask a new question, though there is one place to read existing answers and understand what is involved. The phone is so old ([discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) 4 years ago) that [searching on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nokia%202600%20classic%20retrieve%20files%20broken%20screen&filter=0) provides little help.